# Redirecting multiple ports with socat

Tags: networking, redirect

I would like to use `socat` to redirect some ports and I found a socat daemon [here](https://github.com/asaif/socat-init/blob/master/socat). However this daemon lacks documentation and I could only setup for one port redirect. Is there any syntax to make `socat` or this daemon (or another daemon) to setup multiple individual ports redirecting?

Edit 1:
A possible solution found [here](http://www.howforge.com/how-to-forward-port-in-user-space-using-socat).

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get install socat` to install socat including man pages.

Comment: Why not use multiple instances of `socat`?

Comment: socat is not a damon, I will have to write one daemon per port as the socat accepts only one redirect per command.

Comment: What is the command you use to redirect one port?

Comment: The most basic is something like "socat TCP4-LISTEN:3392,fork TCP4:192.168.10.102:3389". It runs until you close by Ctrl+C or something like. I can't setup more than one redirects in one single line. The solution is setup a daemon for each socat redirect, but the script I found didn't make it and only works for one redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Run multiple instances in background

You could run multiple instances of `socat` in the background in one command.

I use `sleep N` instead of `socat ...N... ...N...` for an example:

```
echo -n 1 2 3 | xargs -d ' ' -I% bash -c '(sleep % ; echo slept % ) &'
```

The `()` and the `echo slept %` part is only needed to have some example output, so your actual command would be simpler; `%` will be replaced by one of the port listed after echo:

```
echo -n 3392 3393 3394 | xargs -d ' ' -I% bash -c 'socat TCP4-LISTEN:%,fork TCP4:192.168.10.102:% &'
```

Wit the count of port args `N`, this should also work:

```
parallel -j N -i bash -c 'socat TCP4-LISTEN:{},fork TCP4:192.168.10.102:{}' -- 3392 3393 3394
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork TCP:host1:8080|socat TCP-LISTEN:8081,fork TCP:host2:8082
```